# Need to get the type of the column using ScrollableResults in Hibernate

Tags: scrollableresults

I am generating a report using Hibernate.

Below is the sample code:
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from A, B where A.id= B.Val");
ScrollableResults results  = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

I want to know all the column names and column types before generating an Excel report.

How to achieve this with Hibernate scrollable results?

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `ScrollableResults` interface you'll see it has a method `getType` which returns the Hibernate `Type` of the given column. For example `Type` could be a `StringType` which maps to `VARCHAR`